# Validating API Responses with FlowType

Tags: javascript, facebook, flowtype

So I've figured out so far what `window.fetch` returns a `Response` object [defined here](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/bom.js#L701-L723).

What I want to do now is extend this definition somehow to type check against my specific api. Here's a small example.

I have an endpoint that will asynchronously decrements a number. The response can return with a 400 error or a 200 with some JSON payload.

So I've created an `interface` to help with these responses:

```
interface ErrorResponse<S,T> {
  status: S,
  statusText: T,
}

interface JSONResponse<S,J> {
  status: S,
  json(): Promise<J>,
}
```

I'm using some generics so I can specify exactly what the responses are:

```
type DecrementJSON = { count: number }
type DecrementResponse = ErrorResponse<400,string>
                       | JSONResponse<200,DecrementJSON>
```

Then I have my api request:

```
export const decrement = (count : number) : Promise<DecrementResponse> =>
  fetch('/dec', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ count }),
  })
```

And I get this error:

```
src/api/index.js:18
 18:   fetch('/dec', {
       ^ function call
 17: export const decrement = (count : number) : Promise<DecrementResponse> =>
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ union: type application of polymorphic type: class type: ErrorResponse | type application of polymorphic type: class type: JSONResponse. This type is incompatible with
704: declare function fetch(input: string | Request, init?: RequestOptions): Promise<Response>;
                                                                                     ^^^^^^^^ Response. See lib: /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_2cb52cf2/bom.js:704
  Member 1:
   14: type DecrementResponse = ErrorResponse<400,string>
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ type application of polymorphic type: class type: ErrorResponse
  Error:
   14: type DecrementResponse = ErrorResponse<400,string>
                                              ^^^ number literal `400`. Expected number literal `400`
  664:     status: number;
                   ^^^^^^ number. See lib: /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_2cb52cf2/bom.js:664
  Member 2:
   15:                        | JSONResponse<200,DecrementJSON>
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ type application of polymorphic type: class type: JSONResponse
  Error:
   15:                        | JSONResponse<200,DecrementJSON>
                                             ^^^ number literal `200`. Expected number literal `200`
  664:     status: number;
                   ^^^^^^ number. See lib: /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_2cb52cf2/bom.js:664
```

Try it yourself [here](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAdgFwKYBOUAhgMZ5gCiBBcBASngM4AOcWTeAPAMoA0AFQB8YAN6owYJjmI4ArkwBcYfhKkz5TAXgAeOZQL6oAvumz4iZCgCkeAeQByjVu068+1keMnTZC5aqSAFZM7AAUAJTKAAq0ALYYbp5Gpqg4AJ4sFAAieKQEeHF4uLaOYAC8YmCkcHK4ylhycQBGhGCmGVlgufmFxTjObBwUldS0DMxDbgAsAAyzfNIE2ADmQmqSm1vbO2AAPmClTpOu3ABM83w9BUUl9g7rqLpsBDjVrm8AJnk3-RVgYRqdTeDSarQIETAMXiiW41z6uEGpxE5XWkigeBwpAAFmEAOTAb6kPF8MQbMBFHDYuCfZR46J2HgCEnk7F4YjfAhKMk7ACCpHILH0YDxxBYLBgGFIsgw7GAIXYLJ2eIAwux8LgALQCTJ4PF0sUSqUyuUKrBKzbGIxbZo09LKI4AOiWqwwUHSYVE72B7Qi1t9qCAA). Thanks

---

Thanks @vkurchatkin for pointing out the issue with validation. I've updated the function to do all the validation internally:

```
type DecrementResponse = { status: 400, error: string }
                       | { status: 200, data: { count: number } }

export const decrement = async (count : number) : Promise<DecrementResponse> => {
  const response = await fetch('/dec', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ count }),
  })
  if (response.status === 400) {
    return {
      status: 400,
      error: response.statusText,
    }
  }
  if (response.status === 200) {
    const result = await response.json()
    return {
      status: 200,
      data: result,
    }
  }
  throw new TypeError(`Unknown response status: ${response.status}`)
}
```

The only thing that doesnt really make since is why I didnt have to validate the actual deserialized json data.

---

Another simple example that doesnt type check is [this one](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVxhgBYBdcAOAzgFyYDmAlrtgK4BGAdAMZwC2wUAhswKb1w4Aa07wEwevHrA2XIrl4AnYDErSBbRgCsiAYgAyAdgCMx1JQB2Cxdz5gAyri65aRAEq8iBOBaK8APPYAfGAA3qhgYPLOriQOqAC+6LgAngS8YACCBJQeXj5+YAC8Dk4u7p7evgEATAAMdSEAPqUxFfnV-gAsDUHorL64YFw5xcNEKRbMYAAUAJRgcQAKiuyUfv7ZuZUFvCFFIeGRA-JgijvVY1wIXNRgULy4zNgzAOQIH4zkguQwvCzsV5zCJgShQWbnDp+RjRcrFIolep1BZHSJnR60RQWdFQ3gghJgXgwQpgiEXaGw1zwxENFEgyLnFxYnFVPz4kE0VZICy8JAAFTSvAAoopVoo3rQLEILIgomVXEDEkA):

```
/* @flow */

// https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/bom.js#L711
interface StatusResponse<S> {
  status: S
}

type ApiResponse = StatusResponse<200> | StatusResponse<400>

const api = async () : Promise<ApiResponse> => {
  const response = await fetch('www.google.com')
  if (response.status === 200) {
    return response
  } else if (response.status === 200) {
    return response
  }
  throw new TypeError('unknown status')
}
```

Seems to me like that should work though since we're validating the statuses...

Comment: The problem is that you don't do any validation, so Flow points it out.

Comment: what kind of validation? The Response type says that status is a number...

Comment: it's a number, but you expect only 200 or 400

Comment: interesting. so I would need to create a JSON validator as well to asset that the "any" object is of the schema I expect?

Comment: or is there some way of casting / asserting?

Comment: @vkurchatkin I've added a new code snippet with some validation and a followup question

Comment: response.json() returns `Promise<any>`, so flow doesn't force you to do validation

Comment: interesting. so after reading [this comment](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/pull/1887#discussion_r75804022) it seems the if the response status was `$Subtype<number>` then I wouldn't have these validation issues?